# Shopify GraphQL Admin API Query Filtering Not Working (Works In GraphQL App)

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am trying to retrieve orders that are tagged with `Ship` from the Shopify GraphQL Admin API. But when I use a backend NodeJS service to call the Admin API, the Tag filtering query doesn't work and I get no results.

When I run the following query in the GraphQL app (https://shopify-graphiql-app.shopifycloud.com/) in my Shopify store it works great and I only get orders tagged with `Ship`:

```
{
  orders(first: 10, query: "tag:'Ship'") {
    nodes {
      id
      tags
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run the same query from my backend nodejs service it doesn't work and returns zero results:

```js
export const getShipOrders = async (accessToken) => {
  const shopGraphQl =
    "https://#########.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/graphql.json";

  const url = shopGraphQl;

  const ORDERS_QUERY = `
query {
  orders(first:10, query: "tag:'Ship'") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        tags
      }
    }
  }
}
  `;

  const body = {
    query: ORDERS_QUERY,
  };

  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Shopify-Access-Token": accessToken,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });

  console.log(`status = ${res.status}, ${res.statusText}`);
  console.log(
    "data returned:\n",
    JSON.stringify((await res.json()).data.orders.edges, null, 2)
  );
};
```

If I remove `query: "tag:'Ship'"` it returns results, so I know the GraphQL API is working to some extent.

The docs say they support Tag queries - https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2022-04/queries/orders#argument-orders-query

So I can't think what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are the orders you are trying to get older than 60 days? If they are you need the `read_all_orders` scope to request them.

Comment: @drip, no they are not. As I mentioned, the query works properly in the Shopify GraphQL app. But that's useful to know anyway, thanks.

Comment: @MasterBrog Have you found a solution? I am having the same problem right now.

Comment: Hi @Guillaume Please share if you have a solution to this problem. I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Same issue here. Why are Shopify's docs hot garbage?